# imagemagick doesn't delete tmp files

Tags: imagemagick, carrierwave, rmagick

I have an app that uses Carrierwave, S3 and rmagci. 
more or less following http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads but just upload to S3 instead of local.

I noticed the temp files in public/uploads/ does not get deleted after an image gets created. This causes my computer to feel up over time and crash.

I looked around and the only solution i found was to write a cron job to delete them http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=15960

any idea if there is a better way to do this in the code rather than a cronjob?

Comment: ImageMagick should delete its own temp file if the process finishes successfully. If it crashes or runs out of space in /tmp, then it will not be able to clean them up. ImageMagick files in /tmp should have "Magick" or "ImageMagick" in the name. Anything else there is not from ImageMagick

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of January 2013, there is no official way to delete temporary files, so imagemagic leaves you to do it yourself. I also use a cron job that runs every 20 minutes since the temporary files are 10+ GB in size.

Comment: `sudo find /tmp/ -name "magick-*" -type f -delete` this will do the job, also posted it as an answer for better visibility

Comment: I did not see any open issue in image magick official repo @KuldeepDangi - please share if you have any info if they handling officially implicitly with any of the version.

Comment: Is this changed recently?

Answer (score 5):

It means your ImageMagick installation is NOT functioning properly!

The fact that it leaves magick-* files in tmp says that ImageMagick process died and that's why it didn't delete those files. You should configure memory limits etc. Refer http://www.imagemagick.org/script/resources.php

Answer (score 3):

I've had this problem for a period of time, my code issue was that I didn't use the destroy function:

```
$im->destroy();
```

When calling the destroy function it will delete the temp files that are made under the `/tmp` directory.
This is for PHP and maybe it will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

It is always better to use a task based approach and not to clog up the runtime with deleting stuff. just run the task once a day.