# Set temporary directory for single ImageMagick convert call

Tags: python, imagemagick

I'm using ImageMagick to batch-convert many PDF files in parallel to PNG with something like

```
convert /my_path/my_pdf.pdf /my_path/output_directory/output.png
```

unfortunately, it clutters my /tmp directory as reported in several bug tickets and questions on Stack overflow (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44900353/change-tmp-for-imagemagick) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875046/imagemagick-doesnt-delete-tmp-files)). Even more unfortunately, the answer always seems to be something like

> Create a cron job to delete the /tmp directory, basically running `rm /tmp/magick-*` on a regular base

I have two problems with this approach:

1. It seems very dirty and I don't know exactly when to invoke it
2. If I run `rm /tmp/magick-*` after each convert call I'm not sure if it doesn't hurt other convert calls, as I might remove files that are still being needed by another process that runs in parallel

Temporary files are needed by ImageMagick, so my ideal solution would be to specify a unique temporary directory for each `convert` call, which I will clean up programatically after the call, without endangering other processes.

Is there a way to do this? Or is it safe to simply run `rm /tmp/magick-*` after each convert call, as temporary files are locked while they are still being used, making this a safe operation to call any time?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out how to actually tell ImageMagick's convert to put the temporary files into a [specific directory](http://imagemagick.sourceforge.net/http/www/FAQ.html), so my solution in Python looks something like this (at least when running on Linux):

```py
from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory

with TemporaryDirectory() as temporary_directory:
    subprocess.run(
        ["convert",
         "/path/to/my/file.pdf",
         "/path/to/my/output.png",
        env=dict(os.environ, TMPDIR=temporary_directory)
    )
```

This ensures that all temporary files created by ImageMagick get cleaned up after the conversion and I'm not leaving stuff behind, even if `convert` crashes.

Comment: You can also use `MAGICK_TEMPORARY_PATH=temporary_directory` as an environment variable.